# Internet Explorer 8 DOCTYPE ignored/commented

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make my web application work in IE8. There are some problems with the Offset and placement of some elements.

The application works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9/10 but when I set the "Document Mode" for IE8 this `<!DOCTYPE html>` is commented like this `<!-- DOCTYPE html -->` if I put the "Document Mode" back to IE9 it is fine.

I have tried using other declarations

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

but I get the same result commented string in IE8.

How can I make IE8 accept doctype?

**UPDATE:**

I think that you are right Jukka K. Korpela, I have noticed now that even when I open google.com it has commented doctype in IE8.

My app in IE9:

[image: This is how my app looks like in IE9]

My app in IE8:

[image: This is how my app looks like in IE8]

The offset is -250 in IE8.

Comment: Have you included the `<html>` opening tag after `<!doctype html>`? Try cross-referencing the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com).

Comment: Yes there is `<html>` tag after doctype, same result. I'll try with Boilerplate.

Comment: HTML5 Boilerplate is not helping either.

Comment: Hmm...is the doctype the first thing in your document? If you have anything before it, it'll go into quirks mode.

Comment: Oh, already answered below : )

Comment: Please specify what the observed problems are and why you think they depend on doctype being ignored. It is normal that on IE 10, when you set “Document Mode” to IE 8, the doctype is shown as commented out. This is just an oddity in IE developer tools.

Comment: The problem was caused by div tag that was not closed. Other browsers worked fine with it or ignored it, but not IE8.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` should be fine for making IE go into standards mode.

The most common reason it doesn't work is because you have some other content ahead of it. The doctype must be the ***very* first thing** in the page -- even white space above it can make it invalid.

Also, if your files are saved with UTF-8 encoding, make sure that it is "UTF-8 Without BOM", because the invisible BOM (byte order mark) at the start of the file can also have the same effect.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don’t think there’s *any* evidence of BOM in HTML files causing any problems in browsers currently in use. There are many rumors, and they can do some harm, since BOM is actually useful in making sure that the document will be treated as UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I can't test it now as I don't have IE8 to hand (and IE9/10 doesn't have the white space issue at all). I can say that I've come across this problem with BOM myself, and resolved it by re-saving without BOM, so I know it's an issue. I can't tell you much more about the circumstances because it was some time ago, but I did see it happening. I disagree about the BOM being useful: I've seen it be the cause more of encoding problems than the solution; any time you see the characters `ï»¿` it's a rogue BOM, and [it crops up a lot](https://google.com/#output=search&q="ï»¿").